# Determining the amount of time between NOW (local time) and next DST change in [Ruby]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Ruby we can find the current time in a particular Time Zone and determine if it is currently DST in that timezone.

```
pry(main)> t = Time.now.in_time_zone('America/Los_Angeles')
=> Tue, 02 Sep 2014 18:14:25 PDT -07:00
pry(main)> t.dst?
=> true
```

I'm looking to find the time difference between `t` and when `t.dst?` next changes.

Is there a way to figure out when the next DST change occurs?

```
# pseudo code
dst_time = # Time when next DST occurs
local_time = Time.now.in_time_zone('America/Los_Angeles')
time_till_dst_change = dst_time - local_time
```

Comment: It does not appear that this information is available in the ruby `time` stdlib. You can find information about the pattern for DST changes at http://www.webexhibits.org/daylightsaving/b.html and an example function (US-only) at https://github.com/harajune/geektool/blob/8d190729aeb31eccde33ebfef5f89222dd50e449/lib/ruby/date2/sample/daylight.rb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get this info from the [`tzinfo`](http://tzinfo.github.io) gem. It can either parse the system timezone files or use the data from the `tzinfo-data` gem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'tzinfo'

tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get('America/New_York')
puts "Next timezone change is at #{tz.current_period.end_transition.datetime}"
```

This prints:

```
Next timezone change is at 2014-11-02T06:00:00+00:00
```